# EXCEL SCRIPT TO COPY COLUMN TO END OF TABLE AND RENAME IT

Tags: excel, office-scripts

Basically we are using a powerapp to do the register. We do this once a week and it populates a column called "Attendance" with the value "Present" For each child that attends.

However before the next register happens I require the attendance column to be clear. In order to do this I would require the attendance column to be copied to a new column with "today" date".

I have managed to create a column with "today" date but need help in copying the values over. You can see the code i have used to create a column. The attendance column is column M.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  let x = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

  let sh = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
  let tbl = sh.getTable("FBRegister")
  tbl.addColumn().setName(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    let x = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

    let sh = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
    let tbl = sh.getTable("FBRegister")
    let todayColumn = tbl.addColumn(); // Save the new column
    todayColumn.setName(x); // Set the name to today's date

    // Get the attendance column, excluding the header
    let attendance = tbl.getColumn('Attendance').getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();

    // Copy values from attendance column to the new column
    todayColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().setValues(attendance.getValues());

    // Clear attendance column
    attendance.clear();
}
```

I've assumed the attendance column is named "Attendance", but if not, you can modify that line (`let attendance = ...` ) accordingly. Additionally, the last line of code clears the attendance column once the values have been copied over, but you can comment out/delete that line if you don't want that.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you soo much! This has helped massively! May God Bless you!